# Can I fix my Grub Bios parition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I Have made a dual boot with ubuntu and Enso OS, I have come to make the decision that I wanna use Enso insted of ubuntu!
Something i noticed a while back when i was trying to reclaim a partion for my ubuntu partion and I was not able to becouse the "bios_grub" Partion was in the way.
How do I Move, Delete, Get Passed, Whatever works so i can make my partion bigger?

Comment: If gpt and using BIOS, not UEFI to boot you must have a bios_grub partition. But it is just unformatted 1 or 2MB space. If you have live installer, you can erase the bios_grub, move partitions around with gparted, and then create new bios_grub and totally reinstall grub. Often easier with advanced options in Boot-Repair. Not sure what Enso is or if it works with Boot-Repair. Use Ubuntu live installer & Boot-Repair for best results. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair If UEFI install, you do not need bios_grub, but must then have an ESP - efi system partition.

Comment: Hai, after deleting my bios_grub i can still not reclaim the partion! I provide a screenshot here of my GParted: http://imgur.com/a/ilsbQ

Comment: That is showing already deleted?  Since you show ESP- efi system partition as sda1, always boot in UEFI mode, never in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode.

Comment: Thx, just booting it with UEFI worked! I got grub set up and I can boot in to my Enso OS Just fine, The loading screen is stretched out instead of having a black box around it but that does not really matter!